# How to create a serializer for a GIS Point to use with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, gis, geodjango

I've created an endpoint that will return some serialized models (`available` and `unavailable`) and a couple of geographic points (`sw` and `ne`) that define the bounding box around those models. I'll determine the extents of all of the `Listing`s returned and will defined `sw` and `ne` accordingly.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = ListingPhotoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        exclude = []


class ListingAvailabilityBBoxSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    available = ListingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    unavailable = ListingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    sw = PointSerializer(read_only=True)
    ne = PointSerializer(read_only=True)
```

But `PointSerializer` for `Point` (as defined in `django.contrib.gis.geos`) doesn't exist, as far as I know. Is there a `PointSerializer` I haven't yet found? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with something that works best for me. At first I tried installing the `drf-extra-fields` package and creating a serializer like so:

```
from drf_extra_fields.geo_fields import PointField

class PointFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    point = PointField()
```

That worked as far as I tested, but it didn't play well with `drf-spectacular`, which I'm using for documentation. Plus it serializes points slightly differently that the `model.PointFields` that were already in my existing models.

The best solution for me was to create a `Model` just for the purposes of creating a model-based serializer. I set `managed` to `False` so it wouldn't create a table in the database.

```
class PointModel(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326)

    class Meta:
        managed = False


class PointFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PointModel
        fields = ["point"]
```